# Using a formula which uses dynamic text based on an outside workbook

Tags: excel

I need to explain how the workbook is designed so that the formula I'm trying to use makes more sense.

The workbook I'm trying to get data from has dates that run horizontally at the top and holidays for specific countries for a given date written vertically in adjacent cells. Countries will not always be located in the same row and not everyday will have the same number of countries for the previous day(s). For example, using letters to represent arbitrary row and column numbers,

```
workbook1

           col a      col b       col c
row 1    1/1/2017    1/2/107    1/3/2017
row 2
row 3    Spain       Canada     Australia
row 4    Colombia    Spain      Vietnam
row 5    Vietnam     England
```

In *another* workbook, I have something like:

```
workbook2

  col a       col b               col c                              col d                                      col e 
  date    date column no    date column letter                        code                                   Spain
1/1/2017        a                   x            ="'[workbook1.xlsx]sheet'!$" & x & ":$" & x
```

In the `date column no` column, I have a formula that gives me the column number from the first workbook where the date to the left exists. Using this number, I convert it to its equivalent in letters under the `date column letter` column. Using this, I was trying to build a dynamic `MATCH` formula in `workbook2` which would just tell me if it found the country in the first workbook. The match formula would be placed right under "Spain" and be written `=MATCH(E2, D2, 0)`. This doesn't produced the desired results. I'm not sure than writing the external reference as a string in column d of `workbook2` and feeding it to the formula is making it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for all these helper columns and no need to translate a column number into a column letter. If you use Index, you can build a range based on the column number.

```
=MATCH(E1,INDEX([Workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1!$3:$3,MATCH(A2,[Workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1!$1:$1,0)):INDEX([Workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1!$20:$20,MATCH(A2,[Workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1!$1:$1,0)),0)
```

This formula has been applied in cell E2 of the workbook in the foreground. Workbook1 is in the background. The formula builds a range using two Index formulas. The first one finds the correct column and returns the cell in row 3. The second index finds the correct column and returns the cell in row 20. The two returned ranges are then combined into a contiguous range with the ":" operator. The range is now the correct column, row 3 to row 20. This range is then fed into the Match function which tries to find "Spain" or the value of cell E1 in that range.

[image]

Note that Workbook1 must be open for the formula to work. If it is not open, the formula returns the #Ref! error.

If the country in E1 is not found in the range, the formula returns the #N/A! error. You can suppress this by wrapping the whole formula into an IfError or `IF(IsNumber(theformula),"found","not found")`